# Should I use a change handler to populate an array of items from an array of item types?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I'm creating a form with a Javascript array of parts. The user will select a part type from a drop down menu, then from the next dropdown menu, select an item from that part type. I believe a change handler in my parts type is the way to go, but can't find examples of using this in my .js file alone. Here is what I have so far:

```
//Creates List of Part Types
function populateTypeList() {
   let typeSelectList = document.getElementById("partTypes");
   for (const item of types) {
       let el = document.createElement("option");
       el.value = item;
       el.textContent = item;
       typeSelectList.appendChild(el);
   } 
}
//Creates Parts List when user selects Part Type
function populateSelectList() {
   let partsSelectList = document.getElementById("autoParts");
   for (const part of partArray) {
       let el = document.createElement("option");
       if (part.description.length > 30) {
           el.textContent = part.description.substring(0, 30) + " ...";
       }
       else {
           el.textContent = part.description;
       }   
       el.value = part;
       partsSelectList.appendChild(el);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is definitely the way forward but you first need a way to get a list of filters and then a way to use a single item from the filter list to create an array of parts with that specific filter.

The first step is to take your entire `partArray` and use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to create a list of types. `Set` will remove all duplicate values so that no filter type is in the list more than once. This is accomplished with the following code.

```
const types = [...new Set(
  partArray.map(({ type }) => type)
)];
```

It loops over the entire array and uses [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array with only the value each `type`. So the result would be `['AIR CONDITIONING', 'BODY', 'BRAKES', ...etc]`. That result is put into the `Set` which makes removes all duplicates. Then the `...` spread operator is used to put every value of the `Set` into a new array.

Now you need a way to get the right parts from the `partsArray`. Create a function which filters the `partsArray` array and returns a new array of parts with that specific type. The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is useful for this.

```
const getPartsByType = filterType => partsArray
  .filter(({ type }) => type === filterType);
```

The example here below uses your provided data and the methods here above to create a list of types and uses those types as values to filter parts into groups of types.

I've also added a way to select the chosen part from the parts `<select>` element.

```js
const parts = [{
    "id": 20,
    "status": "Active",
    "type": "AIR CONDITIONING",
    "category": "",
    "subcategory": "",
    "item": "Orifice Tube",
    "description": "Orifice Tube",
    "descriptionfull": "Orifice Tube 38623",
    "qoh": 18,
    "cost": 1.32,
    "price": 11.06
  },
  {
    "id": 62,
    "status": "Active",
    "type": "BODY",
    "category": "PANELS",
    "subcategory": "",
    "item": "Hood, Bare",
    "description": "Hood, Bare",
    "descriptionfull": "Hood, Bare",
    "qoh": 1,
    "cost": 609.15,
    "price": "1,228.29"
  },
  {
    "id": 159,
    "status": "Active",
    "type": "BRAKES",
    "category": "REAR",
    "subcategory": "Rear Brake Kit",
    "item": "Split Pin",
    "description": "Split pin for Rear Brake Kit, requires 2",
    "descriptionfull": "Split pin for the Rear Brake Kit, requires 2",
    "qoh": -2,
    "cost": 0.12,
    "price": 0.23
  }
];

const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
const partSelect = document.getElementById('part');
const partOutput = document.getElementById('selected-part');

/**
 * Loop over the parts array and create a new 
 * array that only contains unique types.
 */
const types = [...new Set(parts
  .map(({ type }) => type)
)];

/**
 * Function to get parts based on a type.
 * Returns an array with part objects.
 */
const getPartsByType = filterType => parts
  .filter(({ type }) => type === filterType);
  
/**
 * Function to get a single part based on
 * the item.
 */
const getPartByItem = filterItem => parts
  .find(({ item }) => item === filterItem);
  
/**
 * Take the first type from the types array and 
 * gets all the items that have that type.
 */
const initialParts = getPartsByType(types[0])
  
/**
 * Takes in description string and cuts the string down
 * to max 30 characters and adds an ellipsis if necessary.
 */
const truncate = (description, limit = 30) =>
  typeof description === 'string' && description.length > limit ?
    description.substring(0, limit) + '...' :
    description;

/**
 * Create option function.
 * Has options for setting a selected and / or disabled element.
 * A disabled and selected element makes a nice prefilled option.
 */
const createOption = (label, value, selected = false, disabled = false) => {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.value = value;
  option.textContent = label;
  option.selected = selected;
  option.disabled = disabled;
  return option;
}

/**
 * Removes all options from a select element.
 */
const removeOptions = ({ options }) => {
  for (let i = options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    options.remove(i);
  }
}

/**
 * Populate types.
 */
const popuplateTypes = types => {
  for (const type of types) {
    const label = type.toLowerCase();
    const option = createOption(label, type);
    typeSelect.append(option);
  }
}

/**
 * Populate parts and remove previous parts.
 */
const populateParts = parts => {
  const defaultOption = createOption('Choose part', '', true, true);
  removeOptions(partSelect);
  partSelect.append(defaultOption);
  for (const { item, description } of parts) {
    const label = truncate(description); // Description limited to 30 characters
    const option = createOption(label, item);
    partSelect.append(option);
  }
}

// Listen for a change of type, then update the choices
// of the parts list based on that choice.
typeSelect.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  const { value } = target;
  
  // Get the parts based on the selected option value.
  const selectedParts = getPartsByType(value); 
  
  // Populate parts select with new parts.
  populateParts(selectedParts);
  
  // Clears the output element's content.
  partOutput.innerHTML = ''
});

// Listens for a change of item, then gets that single item
// from the parts array and outputs it as JSON.
partSelect.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
  const { value } = target;
  
  // Get a single part based on the value.
  const part = getPartByItem(value);
  
  // Outputting the part as JSON in a <pre> tag will make it readable.
  // The <code> tag is to let the browser know it's code :).
  partOutput.innerHTML = `
    <pre><code>${JSON.stringify(part, null, 2)}</code></pre>
  `;
});

// Instantly populate the types and parts.
// The parts list will be based on the first available type
// in the types array.
popuplateTypes(types);
populateParts(initialParts);
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

#selected-part {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid rgba(118, 118, 118);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  min-height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

pre {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<label for="type">Type</label>
<select id="type" name="type"></select>

<label for="part">Part</label>
<select id="part" name="part"></select>

<label for="output">Chosen Part</label>
<output id="selected-part"></output>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Emiel. I've been studying this in relation to my project and it has helped some. I have my array in a separate .js file that will be used to populate the part types and also the parts available once the type is selected. Can you assist with modifying your example to refer to another .js file instead of populating the arrays with strings and objects?

Comment: Sure, but I have no idea what your other file looks like. It would help a lot if you'd include (a sample of) the actual data that you use to populate your select elements. Are they in global variables or do you use `import` / `export` modules.

Comment: partArray = [
    {
      "id": 20,
      "status": "Active",
      "type": "AIR CONDITIONING",
      "category": "",
      "subcategory": "",
      "item": "Orifice Tube",
      "description": "Orifice Tube",
      "descriptionfull": "Orifice Tube  38623",
      "qoh": 18,
      "cost": 1.32,
      "price": 11.06
    },
    ] I get my array of part types by getting the different type elements, then populate my parts array when the user selects the type.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. If you add a larger sample in which you have multiple items, with multiple types, so you can actually see the changing data. Then I'll modify the answer. Is the `partArray` you're only set of data or is there also a `typesArray`?

Comment: {
      "id": 62,
      "status": "Active",
      "type": "BODY",
      "category": "PANELS",
      "subcategory": "",
      "item": "Hood, Bare",
      "description": "Hood, Bare",
      "descriptionfull": "Hood, Bare",
      "qoh": 1,
      "cost": 609.15,
      "price": "1,228.29"
    },

Comment: {
      "id": 159,
      "status": "Active",
      "type": "BRAKES",
      "category": "REAR",
      "subcategory": "Rear Brake Kit",
      "item": "Split Pin",
      "description": "Split pin for Rear Brake Kit, requires 2",
      "descriptionfull": "Split pin for the Rear Brake Kit, requires 2",
      "qoh": -2,
      "cost": 0.12,
      "price": 0.23
    },

Comment: Yes, partArray is my only set of data. I wanted to create a types array but still refer to the parts array to populate the parts list that have the same type as the type selected by the user.

Comment: Alright, I've implemented your data and found a way to make it very dynamic. All you'd have to do now is add more items to your `partsArray`. The functions will dynamically create a list and uses that to filter through your parts. I've also added a way to select a single part based on the second select filter.